# Transaction synchronization on test secondary thread

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm conducting an integration test for a spring-integration process consisting of 2 integration-flows.

The 1st flow grabs a message from the user/test and pushes it into a jdbc-backed (H2DB) message-queue.

The 2nd flow is driven by a transactional poller which grabs the enqueued message from that same queue and writes it to a folder.

The test periodically checks the folder content and succeeds if it manages to find a file inside the folder before a preset timeout.

Sometimes, the test will find the file and start to shut-down the Spring context before the poller transaction has time to commit, in which case my test dies a horrible death and curses me with a final "cannot commit JDBC transaction, database not available any longer" exception.

1) how can I avoid that my test exits before the poller transaction is committed ?

Note: because the poller transaction doesn't live inside the test thread, I can (probably) *not* make use of the usual goodies provided by Spring for transactional testing.

My current idea is to check not only for the existence of the file but also to assert if the message queue is empty. I believe that the poller transaction should prevent the test thread from seeing an empty queue until the transaction is committed (no dirty-read）.

2) does Spring (integration) default transaction isolation level with H2 guarantees me to avoid dirty-reads ?

Comment: It's better to use a flag indicating whether the poller thread should continue his work.
Another thread who is responsible for the database shutdown should turn off the flag and wait until  the poller thread finishing

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have that poller to be stopped before you exit the test. 
Or stop an `AbstractEndpoint` for that queue channel before the end of that test method. Or consider to use a `@DirtiesContext` if you rely on the Spring Testing Framework for application context management.

The problem is that poller really works in its own scheduled thread and when your test is ready to assert against some polling results, the process is still works on the background for other polling cycles.

The Spring Integration support is fully based on Spring TX foundation, so default `isolationLevel` is exactly that one you see on the `@Transactional`:

```
/**
 * The transaction isolation level.
 * <p>Defaults to {@link Isolation#DEFAULT}.
 * <p>Exclusively designed for use with {@link Propagation#REQUIRED} or
 * {@link Propagation#REQUIRES_NEW} since it only applies to newly started
 * transactions. Consider switching the "validateExistingTransactions" flag to
 * "true" on your transaction manager if you'd like isolation level declarations
 * to get rejected when participating in an existing transaction with a different
 * isolation level.
 * @see org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttribute#getIsolationLevel()
 * @see org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager#setValidateExistingTransaction
 */
Isolation isolation() default Isolation.DEFAULT;
```